# Rectangle bringing on camera in ZBar scanner?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How can we bring rectangle on camera for barcode scanning like red laser with scanningound? is there any built in property?I tried following:

```
 reader.readerView.tracksSymbols = YES;
reader.readerView.trackingColor = [UIColor redColor];

[reader setShowsZBarControls:NO];
reader.readerView.tracksSymbols = TRUE;
scanner.accessibilityFrame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 300);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the rectange as an overlay on your camera view.Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
    {
        // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
        ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
        reader.readerDelegate = self;
        reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

        ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
        reader.showsZBarControls = NO;

        [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                       config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                           to: 0];
        // present and release the controller
        [self presentModalViewController: reader
                                animated: YES];
        reader.cameraOverlayView = [self CommomOverlay];
        [reader release];
    }


-(UIView*)CommomOverlay{  
        UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
       UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,160,203,180)];
        [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlaygraphic.png"]];
       [view addSubview:FrameImg];
        return view;
    }
```

hope this will help you..:)

Comment: This displays the rectangle correctly for me, but it doesn't actually match up to the scanning area. I have to move the camera even closer to the code, outside of the overlay boundaries, before the code is scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
 reader.cameraOverlayView = overLayView;
```

?? i.e `cameraOverlayView` property of `UIImagePickerController`. 
There you can set what ever you want. Hope this is what you want.